# Can't get alternative RegEx to work

Tags: regex

I have this RegEx that captures a few groups:

```
VAN - H.Sedin (D.Sedin, A.Edler)

^(\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>.+)\s\((?P<assist1>.+),\s(?P<assist2>.+)\)$

goalscorer = H.Sedin
assist1 = D.Sedin
assist2 = A.Edler
```

I want to make it so that if theres a whitespace at the end of the line, it still captures it, as sometimes there might be one at the end of the line.

I tried doing a bunch of things, most recently:

```
^(\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>.+)\s\((?P<assist1>.+),\s(?P<assist2>.+)\)$|\)\s+$
```

But I can't get it to capture groups now.

Here's a live link to test it:

https://regex101.com/r/mN8fC0/1

Comment: Can you trim the input string?

Comment: The tags of my previous question got inputted for some reason. @Paulie_D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your regex

`^(\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>.+)\s\((?P<assist1>.+),\s(?P<assist2>.+)\)$|\)\s+$`

is looking for one of two alternatives:

`^(\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>.+)\s\((?P<assist1>.+),\s(?P<assist2>.+)\)$`
or
`\)\s+$`

But the alternatives you have in mind are
`\)$`
or
`\)\s+$`

An additional set of parentheses constraining the alternatives will solve this problem:

`^(\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>.+)\s\((?P<assist1>.+),\s(?P<assist2>.+)(\)$|\)\s+$)`

Alternatively, you could just use `\s*` instead of `\s+` and an alternative, like:

`^(\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>.+)\s\((?P<assist1>.+),\s(?P<assist2>.+)\)\s*$`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Non-Capturing Group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) is also good to use with alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [working regex](https://regex101.com/r/mN8fC0/2):

```
^(?P<Name>\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>.+)\s\((?P<assist1>.+),\s(?P<assist2>.+)\)\s?$|\)
```

Notice the `\s?` after the assist1 group.

Comment: but what is `|\)` comparing to the original RegEx?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear about why you use `|\)\s+$` instead of replace `$` with `\s*$`. But this one is working:

```
^(\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>.+)\s\((?P<assist1>.+),\s(?P<assist2>.+)\)\s*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/mN8fC0/3